# get black screen when opening UITabViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My app opens to a UITabViewController. It has 3 UIViewControllers a,b,c as the tabs, connected by a Segue.

It used to work fine but something happened and now when I run my program, the tabs are displayed and it seems that the controller is working (with NSLogs the viewDidLoad of the first tab seems to run) but except for the tabs the whole screen is black and nothing is displayed.

It seems that this happens a lot, but I've tried all the suggestions and so far nothing has worked.

Looking for possible advice on how to deal with this, thanks!

Comment: Please provide some code and screenshot

Answer (score 0):

try to change the view's backgroundcolor of each viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Are you selected starting point in storyboard like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VOop.png)

This is one major reason for black screen.

Second one background image, third one background view colour.

Comment: Yes, My main tabBarViewController is set as my initial ViewController...